# Mail text disappearing on iPhone

Tags: iphone, mail.app

Friend of mine has an iPhone and no other electronics. Says that

> It seems like messages come and go. No content then there it is. I
>   read one message then the other. Went back to the other and it was
>   gone. Happens a lot. Then it turned up again.

I am a **long** way away, and she is very non-technical. So I am really not sure how to help. What should be done?

Answer (score 1):

With the advancements in iOS, a variety of apps are now available that makes it possible to provide remote assistance (just like in Desktops). A couple example os such apps are:

- [Zoho Assist: Remote Support for iOS Devices](https://www.zoho.com/assist/blog/remote-support-for-ios-devices.html).
- [TeamViewer QuickSupport](https://itunes.apple.com/app/teamviewer-quicksupport/id661649585).